# iPhone Native system routines(datagram-socket-type)

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, ios4, streaming

> Sockets are full-duplex communication
>   channels between processes either
>   local to the same host machine or
>   where one process is on a remote host.
>   Unlike pipes, in which data goes in
>   one direction only, sockets allow
>   processes both to send and receive
>   data. NSFileHandle facilitates
>   communication over stream-type sockets
>   by providing mechanisms run in
>   background threads that accept socket
>   connections and read from sockets.
>
> NSFileHandle currently handles only
>   communication through stream-type
>   sockets. If you want to use datagrams
>   or other types of sockets, **you must
>   create and manage the connection using
>   native system routines.**
>
> The process on one end of the
>   communication channel (the server)
>   starts by creating and preparing a
>   socket using system routines. These
>   routines vary slightly between BSD and
>   non-BSD systems, but consist of the
>   same sequence of steps:

1. Create a stream-type socket of a
   certain protocol.
2. Bind a name to the socket.
3. Adding itself as an observer of
       NSFileHandleConnectionAcceptedNotification.
4. Sending acceptConnectionInBackgroundAndNotify
       to this file handle object.

   This method accepts the connection in the
   background, creates a new NSFileHandle
   object from the new socket descriptor,
   and posts an NSFileHandleConnectionAcceptedNotification.

Now I saw Michael answer .
[About the differences between “stream-type” socket and a “datagram” socket type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004352/whats-the-difference-between-a-stream-type-socket-and-a-datagram-socket-type)

Do you have iPhone implementation example for native system routines(datagram-socket-type)?

Comment: The linked question is about stream vs datagram sockets. What is 'native system routine' actually in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok first I found what I needed, with CFSocket API which will allow me to implement UDP Synchronization.

CFSocket API

Sockets are the most basic level of network communications. A socket acts in a similar manner to a telephone jack. It allows you to connect to another socket (either locally or over a network) and send data to that socket.

The most common socket abstraction is BSD sockets. CFSocket is an abstraction for BSD sockets. With very little overhead, CFSocket provides almost all the functionality of BSD sockets, and it integrates the socket into a run loop. CFSocket is not limited to stream-based sockets (for example, TCP), it can handle any type of socket.

You could create a CFSocket object from scratch using the CFSocketCreate function, or from a BSD socket using the CFSocketCreateWithNative function. Then, you could create a run-loop source using the function CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource and add it to a run loop with the function CFRunLoopAddSource. This would allow your CFSocket callback function to be run whenever the CFSocket object receives a message.

Regardless I found AsyncSocket API.

CocoaAsyncSocket supports TCP and UDP. The AsyncSocket class is for TCP, and the AsyncUdpSocket class is for UDP. Each class is described below.

AsyncSocket is a TCP/IP socket networking library that wraps CFSocket and CFStream. It offers asynchronous operation, and a native cocoa class complete with delegate support. Here are the key features:

Queued non-blocking reads and writes, with optional timeouts. You tell it what to read or write, and it will call you when it's done.
Automatic socket acceptance. If you tell it to accept connections, it will call you with new instances of itself for each connection. You can, of course, disconnect them immediately.
Delegate support. Errors, connections, accepts, read completions, write completions, progress, and disconnections all result in a call to your delegate method.
Run-loop based, not thread based. Although you can use it on main or worker threads, you don't have to. It calls the delegate methods asynchronously using NSRunLoop. The delegate methods include a socket parameter, allowing you to distinguish between many instances.
Self-contained in one class. You don't need to muck around with streams or sockets. The class handles all of that.
Support for TCP streams over IPv4 and IPv6.
The library is public domain, originally written by Dustin Voss. Now available in a public setting to allow and encourage its continued support.

AsyncUdpSocket is a UDP/IP socket networking library that wraps CFSocket. It works almost exactly like the TCP version, but is designed specifically for UDP. This includes queued non-blocking send/receive operations, full delegate support, run-loop based, self-contained class, and support for IPv4 and IPv6.

[CocoaAsyncSocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/)

And here is the CFSocket Reference

[CFSocket Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/Reference/reference.html)